# PHP DB access syntax: "$this->db->select..." How do I use "get()"?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am editing somebody else's code and I am a PHP beginner.

I want to access the contents of a column called "email" in the database "tga_purchase_items" where the "id" of the row is "14". I want to save the output to a variable "$sp_email".

The code I have is thus:

```
 $sp_email = $this->db->select("email")->from("tga_purchase_items")->where("id", 14)->get();
```

The variable is coming out empty although the database field is definitely populated.

What am I doing wrong? I am not used to this "->" syntax at all.

Comment: Is this Active Record in CodeIgniter?

Comment: The syntax is "object oriented", we do not know which class is within "db", couse you didnt told us. for example, i have also a DB class which works different than the code above. We can not answer if we do not know how the class db works.

Comment: @KemalFadillah, thank you for clarifying what the code syntax is based on. I didn't even know what to search for previously.

Comment: @prdatur, a fair comment. Any general advice would be great as I am starting fro square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax used in your database leans towards Codeigniter and active record.

If this is the case, the following code will retrieve the email column.

```
$result_set = $this->db->select("email")->from("tga_purchase_items")->where("id", 14)->get();

$result_object = $result_set->row();

$sp_email = $result_object->email;
```

What you're missing is retrieving the data from the result set which you get. The `get()` functions return a result set which is similar to the native MySQLi Result class. This means that you need to retrieve the data you want from this set. There are various functions available in CodeIgniter to do this, namely `row()`, `row_array()`, `result()` and `result_array()` which you can read about on their [manual page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

Comment: This nailed it... 10/10. Thank you Ben.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done too much with CodeIgniter and the Active Record (I prefer Zend Framework) but I think something like this would do the trick:

```
$this->db->select('email');
$sp_email = $this->db->get_where('tga_purchase_items', array('id' => '14'));
```

Look at this for a more detailed explanation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: thank you very much. I had no idea what to even search for so that codeigniter link is great. I will try the code suggestion you provided now.